# Remote form in rails 3 app is submitting as html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've come to my first remote form in a new rails 3 app and i can't get it to submit remotely: it keeps submitting as html.  I've done this ok in other rails 3 apps so am thinking it must just be something i've forgotten.

Here's my form in my html.erb file:

```
      <%= form_for Assignment.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "assignment[task_id]", @task.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "assignment[person_id]", person.id %>            
        <%= submit_tag "Add to task" %>
      <% end %>
```

And here's how it renders out on the page.  I've included the javascript file links as i have a feeling the problem is something to do with the js not being set up properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/person.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.tipTip.minified.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1306857355" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="ErI0bMA1E0JAXwvyVMistPsWc4fg2dG5tDPOgeur358="/> 
  </head> 

  <body class="tasks"> 

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/assignments" class="new_assignment" data-remote="true" id="new_assignment" method="post">
      <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ErI0bMA1E0JAXwvyVMistPsWc4fg2dG5tDPOgeur358=" />
      </div> 
      <input id="assignment_task_id" name="assignment[task_id]" type="hidden" value="2" /> 
      <input id="assignment_person_id" name="assignment[person_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />            
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Add to task" /> 
    </form>      

  </body> 
</html>
```

It all looks like it's being set up properly.  But, when i submit i get this through in my log:

```
Started POST "/tasks/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-08 15:56:42 +0100
  Processing by TasksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ErI0bMA1E0JAXwvyVMistPsWc4fg2dG5tDPOgeur358=", "assignment"=>{"task_id"=>"2", "person_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Add to task", "id"=>"2"}
```

Like i was saying, i think i've just missed out something that i needed to do to hook this up properly.  Here's my Gemfile as well in case that's relevant:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'haml'
gem 'heroku'
gem "heroku_backup_task"
gem 'authlogic', '3.0.2'
gem 'rails3-generators'
gem 'txtlocal', :git => 'git://github.com/epigenesys/txtlocal.git'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'taps' #for heroku db import/export
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'jrails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.4"
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.5.2'  
  gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  gem 'selenium-client'
  gem 'machinist'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

Can anyone see what's missing?
thanks, max

EDIT - dumb mistake on my part: the partial containing the remote form was being called from inside another non-remote form which was calling the same action.  So the outer form was being triggered by the submit button, not the inner remote one.  Doh. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is your "jquery_ujs.js" the same as this file: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Comment: @dmarkow - i diffed them and they are pretty much identical - just a couple of lines with some differences.  I tried swapping them and it didn't help.

Comment: Your form code is set to post to `/assignments`, but your log excerpt is for an update to `/tasks/2`...

Comment: What happens when you set the { "data-type" => "script" } ? It shouldn't be necessary, but I'm seeing this line in my rails_ujs.js:
dataType = element.attr('data-type') || ($.ajaxSettings && $.ajaxSettings.dataType);

Comment: My fault - stupid mistake, see OP.  Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem which I solved by adding :format => :js to the path.

So it would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for :assignment, :url => assignments_path(:format => :js)
```

Comment: rails 4: <%= form_for @assignment, url: assignments_path, format: :js %>

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, though for different reasons. In my case it was due to my use of `form_tag` rather than `form_for`. The latter apparently adds the proper params to make the call go over Ajax.